# Одноразовая аутентификация

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В проекте на asp.net mvc 3 для аутентификации используется вариант аутентификации форм (легаси). Необходимо для отдельной страницы создать "одноразовую" аутентификацию, для того, чтобы пользователь мог аутентифицирован только на промежуток времени, когда он находится на данной странице. Возможно ли это сделать на основе аутентификации форм? Если да, то как именно? Может быть, кто-то даст ссылку. Заранее спасибо!